# Java Servlet Reloading

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, reloading

How to turn on servlet reloading so you don’t have to stop and restart Tomcat every time you want to change and test a servlet? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

turn on Hot code replacement feature of your IDE. or install JRebel.